# Reading Text from Comma-Delimited file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following text file called urlmap.txt in App_Data

```
ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1143, laptops/1143/laptops-for-beginner-experienced-engineers
ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1142, desktops/1142/dynamic-difference-desktops
ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1141, keyboards/1141/bluetooth-ready-keyboards
ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1140, mouse/1140/microsoft-2key-mouse-with-pad
ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1139, mouse/1139/logitech-3key-mouse-auto-shutoff
and about 2000 such entries....
```

I want to pass in a string like "ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1140" and search and retrieve the text in front of it i.e. "mouse/1140/microsoft-2key-mouse-with-pad"

If this string is not found, it retrieves nothing.

Each string in urlmap.txt is unique, so there is no chance of duplication

How can I do this?

This is what I have so far but I am unable to determine how to retreive the text in front of it

```
string line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("App_Data\urlmap.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
          if (line.Contains(mySearchString)) 
          {

          }
    }
}
```

Since the text file contains about 2000+lines, I also need an optimized way of retrieving the record.

Comment: if you want an optimized way of retrieving the record then you should use a database and an index.  you can "home-brew" an index on this file but that is much harder than just putting the data in a db and using the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Split:

```
if (line.Contains(mySearchString)) 
{
   var text = line.Split(",")[1];
   /*do something else with text*/
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Are the other code bits I posted optimized. How would you read this file?

Comment: @IWantToLearn You're doing It as you suposed to do!

Comment: One last thing. I want to append the text "bestproducts/" in front of each line found. So in my example instead of "mouse/1140/microsoft-2key-mouse-with-pad" I want to return "bestproducts/mouse/1140/microsoft-2key-mouse-with-pad". What optimized change do I make?